# Office COM-addin using MinGW

Tags: c++, com, mingw

I want to create a COM-based addin for Office (using IDTExtensibility2 interface), but I want to do it using MinGW compiler, please don't ask me why. But I was unable to find how to do it. I can't even figure out how I suppose to create a COM-DLL in MinGW, how to export classes and etc. Also there seems to be no IDTExtensibility2 interface in the header files. Could you give me an example on how to create COM-DLL in MinGW if it is even possible? Where can I get interface definitions for IDTExtensibility2 and other Office COM-classes for MinGW?

Comment: have a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/216686/how-to-automate-excel-from-c-without-using-mfc-or-import but I haven't tried this in MinGW

Comment: You might be able to use the `IDTExtensibility2` interface definition from [Building an Office 2000 COM Addin with VC++/ATL](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/microsoftofficeoutlook/article.php/c3797/Building-an-Office-2000-COM-Addin-with-VCATL.htm).